# Serving Dynamic Content with Node.js and update after some time

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, dynamic

Basically I am searching to update data on the site after some time. 
Like, after 10 seconds change a work on the DOM.

I am new to node, so I am not sure how to make it.

I thought to make it via JavaScript making a request to the server but I am not sure that is the correct way to do it.

This is what I already made, but I didn't know I can't re-render all the code.

As you can see, I am using express as my server.

```js
app.get('/proof/screen', (req, res) => {
    var selected = {};

    function instance() {

        do {
            selected = orders_[Math.floor(Math.random() * orders_.length)];
        } while(!selected || selected.financial_status !== 'paid' || !selected.shipping_address);

        res.render('proofscreen', {
            name: selected.shipping_address.first_name,
            state: selected.shipping_address.city,
            province: selected.shipping_address.province,
            country: selected.shipping_address.country,
            product: selected.line_items[Math.floor(Math.random() * selected.line_items.length)].title,
            product_link: '#'
        });

        setTimeout(instance, Math.random() * 5000);

    }

    instance();
});
```

So, this code doesn't makes anything it just shows the error: You can't send again the headers.

Comment: You can't change the content from the server, you need to write some clientside js.

Comment: @tkausl Thanks, do you the correct way to request data from the client to the server? Thanks, again!